# How do I create a form control for nest form values

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having so trouble formatting my Reactive forms. I am getting data displayed through a service that I then set as the values for my form. The trouble I am having Is the form data is not formatted correctly so that It would be able to pass through to my back-end API.

**How do I create a form control for nest form values**
The set.value on my form set's the form to these values when I click on edit and check the set values the correct format is displayed:
`{ "id": 1, "productName": "Scotch", "category": { "category": 6, "CategoryName": "Household" }, "fullPrice": 46.5, "salePrice": 35.26, "availability": true, "supplier": { "supplier": 1, "supplierName": "3M" }, "discount": "76%" }`

When I change the form value with my two select a new supplier and category and then check the value with the Json pipe the current value of my file is:
`{ "id": 1, "productName": "Scotch", "category": "Household", "fullPrice": 46.5, "salePrice": 35.26, "availability": true, "supplier": "3M", "discount": "76%" }`

Category and Supplier is represented in my form by select options. Each option should represent both the id and name of options. For example supplier  1 GM  supplier 2 Abbott Medical Optics, Inc.

I know that the problem is how I structured my form in the ts file but I am having trouble creating a from control that would represent those patch values.

**How can I create a form Control to represent the patch values in my ts file**
The formGroup is defined eailer in my html with `<form  [formGroup]="updateProduct" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">`

Form html:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="editMode === i">

          <td><input class="form-control"  formControlName="id"  disabled></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" id="productName"  formControlName="productName" ></td>
          <td >
              <select class="form-control" formControlName="category">
                <option selected="selcected"  id="opt1" ></option>
                <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]= "category.categoryName">{{category.categoryName}}</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          <td><input class="form-control" id="fullprice" formControlName="fullPrice"></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" id="saleprice"   formControlName="salePrice"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="availability"  formControlName="availability" ></td>
          <td>
            <select class="form-control" formControlName="supplier" >
              <option *ngFor="let supplier of suppliers" [value]="supplier.supplierName">{{supplier.supplierName}}</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input class="form-control" formControlName="discount" id="discount" ></td>

        </ng-container>
```

The method that set's my form values are in my subscribe method,so that form sets as soon as it's requested on click by a method in my ts file.

```
this.homeService.getProduct(this.id).subscribe(data => {
  this.product = data;
  this.updateProduct.setValue({
    id: this.product.id,
    productName: this.product.productName,
    category: {
   // this.product.category.category is the category Id. same format as this.product.supplier.supplier
      category:this.product.category.category,
      CategoryName:this.product.category.categoryName
    },
    fullPrice: this.product.fullPrice,
    salePrice: this.product.salePrice,
    availability: this.product.availability,
    supplier:{
      supplier: this.product.supplier.supplier,
      supplierName:this.product.supplier.supplierName
    },
    discount: this.product.discount
  });
}); 
}
```

Ts.file that has my form:

```
    updateProduct = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(''),
      productName: new FormControl(''),
      category: new FormControl(''),
      fullPrice: new FormControl(''),
      salePrice: new FormControl(''),
      availability: new FormControl(''),
      supplier: new FormControl(''),
      discount: new FormControl(''),

    });
```

I tried formatting my form like this

```
    updateProduct = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(''),
      productName: new FormControl(''),
      category: new FormGroup({
        category: new FormControl(''),
        categoryName: new FormControl('')
      }),
      fullPrice: new FormControl(''),
      salePrice: new FormControl(''),
      availability: new FormControl(''),
      supplier: new FormGroup({
         supplier: new FormControl(''),
         supplierName: new FormControl('')
      }),
      discount: new FormControl(''),

    });
```

I did try to nest my supplier and category inputs but It doesn't seem like it's registering my set values. I want to able to pass category as one value but that value is in a object this.product.category.category and this.product.category.categoryName as one form control through my selects.

Comment: Did you try to call `updateValueAndValidity` after `setValue`?

Comment: Have you specified the root formGroup in the template somewhere, because I don't see it in any of the code provided? Something like `<form [formGroup]="updateProduct">`

Comment: Yes, that was just a snippet but it's there.

Comment: have you tried console `data` check what you getting from `data`

Comment: yes, the I know I am getting the correct data.

Comment: You shouldn't have any FormGroup inside your form. The only problem is that the value of your select is the category **name** (since you used `[value]="category.categoryName"`), instead of being the category object itself. You should thus use `[ngValue]="category"` instead (same thing for the supplier of course). Since the empty string is not a valid value for a Category object, you should iinitailize your form control to `null` instead of the empty string, too.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, thank you that was resolved. How do you get the template to display the patched data? ex: ```<option *ngFor="let category of categories" [ngValue]= "category">{{category.categoryName}}</option>```==> I want the category that is selected that matches the patch value to be displayed by default. Right now nothing is being displayed after patch in the select inputs.

Comment: You must make sure that the form control's value is `===` to one of the elements in the list of categories. Having an object with equal properties is not sufficient.

Comment: @JBNizet I set them equal by changing the set value to ```category:this.product.category``` instead of```category: {
      category:this.product.category.category,
      categoryName:this.product.category.categoryName
    }``` It's not selecting it by default.

Comment: You haven't read what I told you. The category must be `===` to one of the categories displayed in the options. They must be the **same** object.

Comment: I did, I am not trying to sound ignorant or not read the manual. But I don't know how to set them equal that was my guess as to how.

Comment: Find the category of the array of categories that has the same ID as the category of your product, ans use that as the value of the category form control.